# Replacing multiple character phrases with an abbreviation list SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, replace

I have a SQL tables below (NOTE: Quotes used to make it easier to read

```
Table1.Description  
"HOUSING,WRAP RECESSED"  
"HOUSING,ASSEMBLY 2-FEED"  
"LENS,FLUSH SUS"  

Table2.Abbreviations  
ASSY = ASSEMBLY  
FD = FEED  
FLUSH = FL  
HSG = HOUSING  
LENS = LNS    
RECESSED = REC
```

I want to update, or something along the lines of replace and create a new table (either is fine), Table1.Description with the Table2.Abbreviations. It should look like this:

```
Table1.Description  
"HSG,WRAP REC"  
"HSG,ASSY 2-FD"  
"LNS,FL SUS"
```

Comment: One approach (not necessarily the best one) would be to use a cursor to go through each row in Table1 and execute a procedure to perform string replacements as many times as needed using the data from Table2 until no replacements can be made.

Comment: Is there any possibility of overlapping substitutions, e.g. "FOOD" becomes "FD" and "FOO" becomes "FU"? If so, you'll need a solution like Dr. Cappelletti's that "tokenizes" the input string before attempting substitutions. Another bit of fun occurs if substitutions can occur recursively, e.g. "FOOD WRAP" becomes "FD WRP" and "WRP" becomes "RP". Do you want to keep substituting all the way down?

Comment: @HABO, all approaches up to now are *row-by-row*. Given there is a sort order of the replacements, this is no problem. One might even replace a phrase to something else and re-replace it after other replacements. In one of my projects we use a function with two parameters: A *key-value-pair*-XML with all replacements and a `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. We use this for complex *multi-level* actions to create CDA-documents out of templates. This works astonishingly fast, as long as you deal with one document only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

A table for your abbreviations

```
CREATE TABLE Abbreviations (LongTerm VARCHAR(100),ShortTerm VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO Abbreviations VALUES
 ('ASSEMBLY','ASSY')
,('FEEd','FD')
,('FLUSH','FL')
,('HOUSING','HSG')
,('LENS','LNS')
,('RECESSED','REC');

GO
```

A function doing the magic

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ReplaceAbbreviations(@string VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @string=REPLACE(@string,LongTerm,ShortTerm)
    FROM Abbreviations;

    RETURN @string;
END
GO
```

a table with your strings

```
CREATE TABLE YourDescription (LongDescription VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO YourDescription VALUES
 ('HOUSING,WRAP RECESSED')
,('HOUSING,ASSEMBLY 2-FEED')  
,('LENS,FLUSH SUS');
GO
```

a simple select using the function

```
SELECT LongDescription
      ,dbo.ReplaceAbbreviations(LongDescription) AS ShortDescription
FROM YourDescription;
GO
```

Cleaning the test scenario

```
DROP TABLE YourDescription;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.ReplaceAbbreviations;
DROP TABLE Abbreviations;
```

The result

```
LongDescription            ShortDescription
HOUSING,WRAP RECESSED      HSG,WRAP REC
HOUSING,ASSEMBLY 2-FEED    HSG,ASSY 2-FD
LENS,FLUSH SUS             LNS,FL SUS
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using dynamic SQL and global search & replace.  This process will essentially "tokenize" the the string to avoid collisions.

I should note, that the Abbreviations would best be in two fields (From, To).  A couple in the sample provided seemed inconsistent (Long > Short and Short to Long).

```
Declare @Table1 table (ID int,Description varchar(500));Insert into @Table1 values (1,'HOUSING,WRAP RECESSED'),(2,'HOUSING,ASSEMBLY 2-FEED'),(3,'LENS,FLUSH SUS')
Declare @Table2 table (MapFrom varchar(50),MapTo varchar(50));Insert Into @Table2 values 
('ASSEMBLY','ASSY'),
('FEED'    ,'FD'),
('FLUSH'   ,'FL'),
('HOUSING' ,'HSG'),
('LENS'    ,'LNS'),
('RECESSED','REC')

Declare @SQL varchar(max)=''
Select  @SQL = @SQL+concat(',(',ID,',''||',replace(Description,'''',''''''),'||'')') From @Table1 --Where ID=2
Select  @SQL = Replace(@SQL,MapFrom,MapTo) 
 From   (
         Select MapFrom=' ',MapTo='|| ||'
         Union All
         Select ',','||,||'
         Union All
         Select '-','||-||'
         Union All
         Select MapFrom = '||'+ltrim(rtrim(MapFrom))+'||'
               ,MapTo   = ltrim(rtrim(MapTo))
          From  @Table2
          Union All
          Select '||',''   -- Remove Any Remaining |
         ) A
Select  @SQL = 'Select * From ('+Stuff(@SQL,1,1,'values')+') N(ID,Value)'
Exec(@SQL)
```

Returns

```
ID  Value
1   HSG,WRAP REC
2   HSG,ASSY 2-FD
3   LNS,FL SUS
```

Comment: I apologize for any confusion, but "=" is not included in the value. I was just trying to say the abbreviation for housing is HSG and so on. So they actually are two columns. Does that help clarify? Thank you for this though! I'd definitely like to see an update if you have one. Thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: What are the two field names?

Comment: @SeanDon See updated answer.  In Table2, I now have 2 fields MapFrom and MapTo

Comment: @SeanDon added one more map of - to trap items like 2-FEED

Answer (score 0):

The general strategy would be to go through each word/abbreviation pair, and update Table1.Description based on each pair. I created a solution using temp tables to illustrate how to do this:

```
CREATE TABLE #table1 (descr VARCHAR(1000))
CREATE TABLE #abbr (word VARCHAR(1000), abr VARCHAR(1000), processed int)

DECLARE @word VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @abbr VARCHAR(1000)

INSERT INTO #table1
        ( descr )
VALUES  ( 'HOUSING,WRAP RECESSED'  -- descr - varchar(1000)

          ),
          ( 'HOUSING,ASSEMBLY 2-FEED'  -- descr - varchar(1000)

          ),
          ( 'LENS,FLUSH SUS'  -- descr - varchar(1000)

          )

INSERT INTO #abbr
        ( word, abr, processed )
VALUES  ( 'ASSEMBLY', -- word - varchar(1000)
          'ASSY'  -- abr - varchar(1000)
          ,0
          ),
          ( 'FEED', -- word - varchar(1000)
          'FD'  -- abr - varchar(1000)
          ,0
          ),
          ( 'FLUSH', -- word - varchar(1000)
          'FL'  -- abr - varchar(1000)
          ,0
          ),
          ( 'HOUSING', -- word - varchar(1000)
          'HSG'  -- abr - varchar(1000)
          ,0
          ),
          ( 'LENS', -- word - varchar(1000)
          'LNS'  -- abr - varchar(1000)
          ,0
          ),
          ( 'RECESSED', -- word - varchar(1000)
          'REC'  -- abr - varchar(1000)
          ,0
          )


WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #abbr WHERE processed = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @word = word, @abbr = abr FROM #abbr WHERE processed = 0

    UPDATE #table1
    SET descr = REPLACE(descr,@word,@abbr)

    UPDATE #abbr
    SET processed = 1
    WHERE word = @word AND abr = @abbr
END

SELECT * FROM #table1
```

Comment: You are walking in the darkness of procedural thinking. Come on! Proceed into the light of set-based approaches. See the proc devil, who invented loops and cursors to lead us poor database people away from the light of set-based solutions. To be honest: My solution is - in the *magic moment* a hidden *RBAR* too. And honest2: Yes, there are moements, where `WHILE` (or `CURSOR`) are a good choice, but these situations are rare...